# Does this form a group ? From Nathan Carter's Visual Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, self-learning

A penny and nickel are placed side by side on a table along with Dime (placed to the right of the two coins). The only allowed action is to perform is the swapping of penny and nickel. Does this forms a group ?

Now, we have two elements in group basically in the set. Are viz {e,a}. Now we have predefined action which is swapping, and swapping is reversible also,deterministic, also any sequence of swaps is valid. Is this correct ?

Comment: I have no idea how to interpret your sentence "we have two elements in group basically in the set".  Your next sentence is correct, and indicates that the set of permissible actions forms a group.  However, this sentence is not really a **proof** that the actions form a group.  For that, you need to make sure that every condition from the definition of a group (as given in your textbook) is satisfied.

Comment: I have written about all four conditions in second last ine of second paragraph

Comment: If that's the case, then your textbook uses an unconventional definition. [This is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition) the definition that I'm used to.  If you want us to check your work, you'll have to tell us how exactly your textbook defines a group.

Comment: 4 rules to be checked. 1. predefined list of actions that never changes. 2. every action is reversible. 3. every action is determinstic. 4 . any sequence of actions is also an action

Comment: In that case you're all set and your answer (except possibly for the confusing first sentence) is correct.

Comment: but what formal proof do you have ?

Comment: Too long for a comment, and I don't want to write it out right now. If you'd like a proof that appeals to the definition that I provided, then perhaps you should post a separate question asking for that.

Comment: Well, it's only a group if there is an implicit assumption that you didn't state: Namely that you are allowed to repeat the process (that is, after you swapped the coins, you are allowed to swap them again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting $a$ as swapping the coins and $e$ as not swapping the coins, we get the set $G = \{e, a\}$ equipped with operation laws
$$ee = e, \\
ea = a, \\
ae = a, \\
aa = e.$$
The axioms you provided are very much appealing to intuition, making it impossible to more formally than you that they are satisfied. What we *can* check formally are the formal group axioms:

1. If $x, y \in G$, then $xy \in G$
2. There exists an *identity element* $e$ satisfying that for any $x \in G$ we have $ex = xe = x$
3. Any element $x \in G$ has an inverse $x^{-1}$ satisfying $xx^{-1} = x^{-1}x = e$
4. The group operation is associative, i.e., for $x,y,z \in G$ we have $(xy)z = x(yz)$.

(Note that these do not exactly correspond to your axioms, but altogether they are equivalent).

The first axiom is satisfied, as can be seen by looking at the operation laws above. Moreover, applying $e$ on either side does not change anything, so $e$ is the identity element in the second axiom. For the third axiom, note that $e^{-1} = e$ and $a^{-1} = a$. Finally, for the fourth axiom, we need to check eight things, e.g.,
$$(ea)a = (a)a = aa = e = e(e) = e(aa).$$

Comment: how are you doing or combining xy ? Do you use binary operation as swap ?

Comment: @ConfusedSimpleton Writing $xy$ means "first do $x$ and then $y$". I am not sure what you mean by "binary operation as swap".

Comment: do you mean first do x to e then do y to resulting config ?

Comment: Which line are you talking about?

Comment: i am talking about your first comment

Comment: Okay maybe I see your confusion. The elements of the group you are describing are "actions", not "states". The states are of secondary importance, what counts is what you *do*. So, in words, when I write $ae = ea$ I say "if you first swap the coins, then do nothing, then this is the same as first doing nothing, then swap the coins".

Comment: Right i see that

Comment: @Levi: Well, strictly speaking, the elements of the group are equivalence classes of actions. For example, swapping the coins twice is not really the same as not doing anything. But it has the same effect on the state space, and therefore the two actions are equivalent. If the state space included a counter that counts your swaps, then the two actions would no longer be equivalent (and indeed, the actions no longer would form a group).